# Bash increment input file name

Tags: bash, file, input

I have been trying to write a better bash script to run a specified program repeatedly with different input files. This is the basic brute force version that works, but i want to be able to use a loop to change the argument before ".txt".

```
    #!/bin/bash

./a.out 256.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 512.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 1024.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 2048.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 4096.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 8192.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 16384.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 32768.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 65536.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 131072.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 262144.txt >> output.txt
./a.out 524288.txt >> output.txt
```

I attempted to make a for loop and change the argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
arg=256

for((i=1; i<12; i++))
{
    #need to raise $args to a power of i
    ./a.out $args.txt << output.txt
}
```

but i get an error on my ./a.out stating that ".txt" does not exist. What is the proper way to raise args to a power of i and use that as the argument to ./a.out?

Comment: The reason you get that error is unrelated to your question about math. The issue there is that you are using `$args.txt` but your variable is `$arg`. So `$args` is empty. If you correct that you'll always use the `256.txt` file in your loop which will actually let you ask the question about math.

Comment: also, do you want `>> output.txt` or `<< output.txt` (as written in your for loop)? AND don't forget to zero out your `output.txt` file before the for loop, so you don't keep old test runs at the top of your file. Good luck.

Comment: i meant >> just miss typed as i just typed that here didn't copy it over. thanks for catching that!

Comment: Unless you don't want to zero out `output.txt`, you'd better write `> output.txt` after the `for` grouping. Even if you really mean `>>`, put it after the `for` grouping anyways.

Comment: as of right now it doesn't matter, may be an improvement for the future. I always appreciate extra suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that's a good point, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all that you need to do:

```
for ((i=256; i<=524288; i*=2)); do ./a.out "$i.txt"; done > output.txt
```

Every time the loop iterates, `i` is multiplied by 2, which produces the sequence that you want. Rather than redirecting the output of each iteration separately to the file, I have also moved the redirection outside the loop. This way, the file will only contain the contents from the loop.

In your question, `$args` is empty (I guess that you meant to put `$arg`), which is why your filename is just `.txt`. Also, you have used `<<` rather than `>>`, which I assumed was a typo.

Comment: as of right now i need to append to the file, but this will change in the near future. Thanks for the quick and professional response.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
seq 12 | xargs -i echo "256 *  2 ^ ({} - 1)" | bc | xargs -i echo ./a.out {}.txt
```

If it's OK, then drop `echo` and add `>> output.txt`

```
seq 12 | xargs -i echo "256 *  2 ^ ({} - 1)" | bc | xargs -i ./a.out {}.txt >> output.txt
```